# Creating an array problem. help please

Tags: java, generics, linked-list

> **Dupe:** [Java Generics Syntax for arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185594/java-generics-syntax-for-arrays)

I want to create an array that will hold linked lists of Integer type..

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        LinkedList<Integer> [] buckets = new LinkedList<Integer>[10];       

    }
}
```

I get an error saying:
Cannot create a generic array of LinkedList

Why is this? Can it be solved?

Answer (score 4):

Generics and ye olde arrays don't get on well (this subject has been done to death meny times, here and elsewhere). Use an (array) list of lists.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap it with another list type, e.g:

```
ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> buckets = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
List<Integer> [] buckets = new LinkedList[10];
```

I don't know why Java doesn't allow generics on arrays given you can just drop the generic on the right (though it will give an unchecked warning this way)

Comment: its because arrays are reified (runtine behavior) and generics uses type erasure at compiletime

Comment: I don't see why the compile cannot check the generics types match, and otherwise treat it as if it wasn't there.