# Java 1.6: Creating an array of List<T>

Tags: java, generics

Why can't I create an array of List ?

```
List<String>[] nav = new List<String>[] { new ArrayList<String>() };
```

Eclipse says "Cannot create a generic array of List"

or

```
ArrayList<String>[] nav = new ArrayList<String>[] { new ArrayList<String>() };
```

Eclipse says "Cannot create a generic array of ArrayList"

or

```
List<String>[] getListsOfStrings() {
    List<String> groupA = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> groupB = new ArrayList<String>();
    return new List<String>[] { groupA, groupB };
}
```

But I can do this:

```
List[] getLists() {
    return new List[] { new ArrayList(), new ArrayList() };
}
```

Eclipse says that List and ArrayList are *raw types* but it compiles...

Seems pretty simple, why won't it work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Generics Syntax for arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185594/java-generics-syntax-for-arrays)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Well, [generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/fineprint.html) give the answer to your question.

> The component type of an array object
>   may not be a type variable or a
>   parameterized type, unless it is an
>   (unbounded) wildcard type.You can
>   declare array *types* whose element type
>   is a type variable or a parameterized
>   type, but not array *objects*.
>
> This is
>   annoying, to be sure. This restriction
>   is necessary to avoid situations like:
>
> ```
> // Not really allowed.
> List<String>[] lsa = new List<String>[10];
> Object o = lsa;
> Object[] oa = (Object[]) o;
> List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
> li.add(new Integer(3));
> // Unsound, but passes run time store check
> oa[1] = li;
>
> // Run-time error: ClassCastException.
> String s = lsa[1].get(0);
> ```
>
> If arrays of parameterized type were
>   allowed, the previous example would
>   compile without any unchecked
>   warnings, and yet fail at run-time.
>   We've had type-safety as a primary
>   design goal of generics.

Comment: "If arrays of parameterized type were allowed, the example above would compile without any unchecked warnings, and yet fail at run-time." This is not the reason. `Object[] sa = new String[10]; oa[1] = new Integer(3);` would also "compile without any unchecked warnings, and yet fail at run-time". The more important point is that it should fail at the point of storing, with an ArrayStoreException (thus arrays are runtime-checked). But the runtime check cannot check generics, that's why creating arrays of parameterized types is disallowed.

Answer (score 14):

You can't create arrays of generic types, generally.

The reason is that the JVM has no way to check that only the right objects are put into it (with ArrayStoreExceptions), since the difference between `List<String>` and `List<Integer>` are nonexistent at runtime.

Of course, you can trick the compiler by using the raw type `List` or the unbound wildcard type `List<?>`, and then cast it (with a unchecked cast) to `List<String>`. But then it is your responsibility to put only `List<String>` in it and no other lists.

Answer (score 1):

No exact answer, but a tip:

Last example has a raw type warning because you omitted the typization of the list; it is generally a better (type safe) approach to specify which object types are contained in the list, which you already did in the previous examples (`List<String>` instead of `List`).

Using arrays is not best practice, since their use contains errors most times; Using Collection classes (List, Set, Map,...) enables use of typization and of convenient methods for handling their content; just take a look at the static methods of the Collections class.

Thus, just use the example of the previous answer.

Comment: But you can't create an array of `List<String>` – that is the point of the question (and the reason the last example was used at all).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to extend `LinkedList<String>` (or `ArrayList<String>`, etc.), then create an array of the subclass.

```
private static class StringList extends LinkedList<String> {}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    StringList[] strings = new StringList[2];
    strings[0] = new StringList();
    strings[1] = new StringList();
    strings[0].add("Test 1");
    strings[0].add("Test 2");
    strings[1].add("Test 3");
    strings[1].add("Test 4");
    System.out.println(strings[0]);
    System.out.println(strings[1]);
}
```

Comment: You could, but that defeats the purpose of generics.