# Specific Java generic array creation

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java 1.6: Creating an array of List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662394/java-1-6-creating-an-array-of-listt)

How can I initialize this array in Java.

```
Vector<Integer>[] c;
```

I already try:

```
Vector<Vector<Integer>[]> a = new Vector<Vector<Integer>[]>();
Vector<Integer>[] c = (Vector<Integer>[])a.toArray();
```

with the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.util.Vector;     at
>   app.Program.main(Program.java:38)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

EDIT:

My problems is that I am client from a class that receives an generic array "T[] args" argument, and in my case T is a generic type such Vector, Thanks

I am new in Java.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? A Vector and Array are similar conceptually, but they are not identical. Are you really trying to create a Vector that contains Integer arrays?

Comment: Why would you use an array if you're using a collection?  From what you've asked, it seems as if you want an array of vectors.  Wouldn't a List of Vectors make more sense?  Hard to say w/o the specifics of why you want an array.

Comment: @Aaron Kurtzhals No, I am trying to create an array of a generic type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can create an array of generics.
Check this out. [Java 1.6: Creating an array of List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662394/java-1-6-creating-an-array-of-listt)

This is because the type information isn't available at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use Vector if you can avoid it.  It was replaced by ArrayList in Java 1.2 (1998)

```
List<List<Integer>[]> a = new ArrayList<List<Integer>[]>();
List<Integer>[] c = (List<Integer>[]) a.toArray(new List[a.size()]);
```

`toArray()` only returns a `Object[]` which cannot be down cast to a specific array type.

BTW If efficiency is an issue, I would avoid using Integer in a collection.  You could use trove instead. `TIntArrayList` is a wrapper for `int[]`

```
List<TIntArrayList> a = new ArrayList<>();
TIntArrayList[] c = a.toArray(new TIntArrayList[a.size()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an array of Vectors:

```
    Vector<Integer>[] c = new Vector[2];
    c[0] = new Vector<Integer>();
    c[0] = new Vector<Object>(); // <- compiletime error
    c[0].add(new Integer(0));
```

We cannot create a "generic array". But the line above creates an array that holds up to *size* vectors. And each array slot can hold a reference to a parametized `Vector`.

We see, that even if the array itself is not generic, the variable c is declared as a generic type this forces us to only put `Vector<Integer>` instances to the array.

So we can add other vectors to the array, if we ignore some warnings...

```
    Vector[] b = c;                    // <- warning
    Vector<Double>[] a = b;            // <- warning
    a[1] = new Vector<Double>();       // <- the array itself allows that
    a[1].add(new Double(0));

    for (Vector<Integer> vector : c) {
        Integer value = vector.get(0); // <- BOOM! (on second iteration)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either remove the generic declaration

```
Vector[] c = new Vector[10];
```

Or replace the array with another vector or list type

```
List<Vector<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Vector<Integer>>();
```