# Create generic List

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

How I can create genric List in Java? I also can pass `Class<T>` instance to the method.

Like this:

```
public static <T> List<T> createList(Class<T> clazz) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

    list.add(clazz.newInstance());

    return list;
}
```

Comment: List is already generic. You can pass whatever type of object you want to a List.Do you want to create your own generic class? That's something easily searchable.

Comment: you've already done that.

Comment: @R.J I think I can't create new ArrayList<T>, because of type-erasure.

Comment: then what is that you require?

Comment: @R.J In other words: I know I can't do like this with Java generics: `new T();`  So I think I also can't do like this: `new ArrayList<T>`

Comment: but you can do something like this:- `list.add((T)"String");`

Answer (score 5):

I don't understand why you want a method at all. You can just do `new ArrayList<String>()`, `new ArrayList<Integer>()`, etc.

If you want to write it as a method, do

```
 public static <T> List<T> createList() {
    return new ArrayList<T>();
 }
```

The return type `List<T>` is inferred by the compiler.

Comment: But does it work? I think I can't create `new ArrayList<T>`. But even if I can do it, according to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5662447/921193 I can't add to it elements

Comment: If you do it outside the method, you will need to use the right type argument (`new ArrayList<String>()`, etc).  

In the method, it is a different story, because `T` is a type parameter. The method creates a generic list of *some type*. The actual type doesn't matter (because of type erasure: the runtime type of `ArrayList<String>` is the same as the runtime type of `ArrayList<Integer>`). 

What you cannot do is add things to a `List<?>`, but we are not doing that in this case:

`List<String> list =createList()`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass the instance to list means you can try this

```
public class info  {

    private int Id;

    public void setId(int i_Id) {
    this.Id = i_Id;
    }

    public int getId() {
    return this.Id;
    }

}

class two{
    private List<info> userinfolist;

    userinfolist= new ArrayList<info>();

    //now you can add a data by creating object to that class

     info objinfo= new info();
     objinfo.setId(10);
     userinfolist.add(objinfo); .//add that object to your list
     }
```