# Array of ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I trying to allocate 3 `ArrayList` as follow  -

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] m_locationArr  = new ArrayList<Integer>[3]
```

and it prompts `Cannot create a generic array of ArrayList<Integer>`

What is wrong here  ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662394/java-1-6-creating-an-array-of-listt

Comment: And a better one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217065/cannot-create-an-array-of-linkedlists-in-java

Comment: The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2927427/484293) is a combination of covariant arrays and type erasure in java.

Comment: If you're trying to create an array of x, y and z point's there's a better solution `ArrayList<Point3D>` with `class Point3D { public int x,y,z; }`