# Unchecked cast warning in Java

Tags: java, casting, warnings

Eclipse says: `Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to ObjectArrayList<Car>` when I do:

```
final ObjectArrayList<Car> icars = (ObjectArrayList<Car>) cars[i];
```

where `cars` is defined as:

```
final Object[] cars = new Object[1000];
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    cars[i] = new ObjectArrayList<Car>();
}
```

Eclipse suggests to add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to `icars` object. But I've read somewhere that annotations are deprecated in Java, so should I leave it as it is?

Comment: Yes. you can leave as it is.

Comment: Are you saying all annotations are deprecated? Got a source?

Comment: "annotations are deprecated in Java" -NO.

Answer (score 6):

The warning is just, well, warning you that the objects in the `cars` array that are being casted aren't guaranteed to be an `ObjectArrayList<Car>`.

It turns out Java doesn't allow array declaration with generic types unless they're unbounded (see [Java 1.6: Creating an array of List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5662394/851811), or this bug report [6229728 : Allow special cases of generic array creation](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6229728)). But *if you could* declare the array like this, you wouldn't be getting the warning:

```
final ObjectArrayList<Car>[] cars=new ObjectArrayList<Car>[1000]; // not allowed
```

If you really want to avoid an unchecked cast you should use a strongly typed collection instead of an array (for instance, a `List<ObjectArrayList<Car>>`).

The [`@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) annotation will just tell the compiler not to show the warning. I wouldn't advice using it unless the warning really annoys you. Reality is you'll be doing an unchecked cast (not a problem if you're certain about the type of the elements in the array).

As a side note, annotations aren't in any way deprecated in Java. Actually, it seems they'll become more powerful with Java 8 (it seems they'll support [JSR 308: Annotations on Java Types](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=308)). Maybe you read that [`@Deprecated`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html) is an annotation instead.

Answer (score 0):

You defined cars as: `Object[] cars` so when you try to put a cars element in icars you are casting from `Object` to `ObjectArrayList<Car>`.

The compiler can't know if all the elements in cars array are `ObjectArrayList<Car>`, so it shows the warning

<strike>To avoid this you can change the cars array definition to:</strike>

```
final ObjectArrayList<Car>[] cars = new ObjectArrayList<Car>[1000];
```

Comment: No I can't, Java does not allow to have an array of generic types.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the `Object[] cars` to be an  `ObjectArrayList<Car>[]` array, then yes, leave it as it is. The compiler only gives you a warning. When **you know** that you can cast, then you don't have to listen to what the compiler says.

If you find the *Warning* annoying, then yes you can add the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.