# How to name a variable dynamically? - Java

Tags: java, android, variables

I want to know how I can name a variable dynamically.

If there are 3 items in a list then it should create 3 different object for each item.
Like:

```
ArrayList<String> list1;

ArrayList<String> list2;

ArrayList<String> list3;
```

So it should count up or anything like that.

if there are 4 items in a list it should create 4 variables.

How can I achieve that?

**Edit:**

I tried this but it says me an error that I can't create a generic array of Info.

```
ArrayList<Info> listForLg[] = new ArrayList<Info>[];
for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfKfzList; i++) {
    listForLg[i] = new ArrayList<Info>();
    listForLg[i].add(logInfo);
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: You are trying to add the object InfoForLog to the ArrayList listForLg which will accept only object of Info as in Line 1. Either change the line1 to ArrayList<Info> to ArrayList<InfoForLog> or change the add only objects of Info to arraylist

Comment: sorry my fault, i wrote the false code in here. I edit it. i have everywhre `<Info`

Comment: @aut_silvia Still you are getting the same error? and what is logInfo in your code?

Comment: I did this, and no error anymore: `ArrayList<Info>[] listForLg = (ArrayList<Info>[])new ArrayList[4];`

Comment: @aut_silvia: casting ArrayList<Info>[] onto ArrayList<Info> is bad programming. Did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Use arrays

```
ArrayList<String> list[] = new ArrayList<String>[3]; //or 4 or n
```

Then access them like

```
list[0] = "123";
```

Comment: hm ok but I have a problem. I have a ArrayList of own object. `ArrayList<Info> list = new ArrayList<Info>();` and then it says me an error that i cant create a generic array of `Info`. Can u help me?

Comment: You could read the generics tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/fineprint.html) or just read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662394/java-1-6-creating-an-array-of-listt) question.

Comment: If `list` is an array of `List`s, then you can't assign a string to it.

Answer (score 2):

Use Array for this...

```
ArrayList<String> yourlist[] = new ArrayList<String>([your size here])
```

Based on index use your variable..

```
yourlist[0] yourlist[1]....and so on
```

Hope this could help

Comment: hm ok but I have a problem. I have a ArrayList of own object. ArrayList<Info> list = new ArrayList<Info>(); and then it says me an error that i cant create a generic array of Info. Can u help me?

Comment: @aut_silvia i think you have different type of objects to be added to the ArrayList. When you declare ArrayList<Info>, then you can only add the object of Info to the above ArrayList. To add different objects to the ArrayList, declare the ArrayList as ArrayList<Object>

Comment: no i just have object of info. that should not be the problem

Comment: You code in your question says that you have an object of InfoForLog as listForLg[i] = new ArrayList<InfoForLog>();

Comment: @aut_silvia your Generic Class are Different..i.e  InfoForLog and Info

Answer (score 1):

Create list or arraylist

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> group = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(4);
```

**or**

```
List<List<String>> group1 = new ArrayList<List<String>>(4);
```

Edit:

```
    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

To add (u can add items dynamically by loop)

```
    group.add(list1);
```

and to get

```
    list2= group.get(0);
```

Comment: Ok and what else. how can I get the 4 variables then?

Comment: @aut_silvia   see edits