# Suppression problems with generically typed Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, generics, type-conversion, suppress-warnings

Why does this give me a type safety warning?

```
MyAwesomeObject<T>[] parent = new MyAwesomeObject[1];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) See also: [Java 1.6: Creating an array of List<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662394/java-1-6-creating-an-array-of-listt)

Answer (score 0):

It's because arrays generally don't go well with generic types. The most common way people handle data structures with generic types is to use Lists.

So for example, you would create a `List<T>` object rather than an array. One reason why arrays don't go well with generics and gives you the type safety warning is because arrays are **co-variant**: meaning that they can contain sub-types.

For example, an array of objects can contain longs and ints, which would fail at run-time when you tried to call items from the array. With Lists, it prevents you from inserting subtypes at compile time that could cause your code to fail at run-time.

So a rule of thumb would be to use a List instead of an array, but if you're really intent on using arrays and are sure that you will not be inserting any sub-types into the array, then you can add the line `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` above the line that you gave.