# ListNode<String> array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create an array of `ListNode<String>` in Java. 
I get this error: "cannot create a generic array of `ListNode<String> []` when I try to create the array as such:

```
ListNode<String> [] array = new ListNode<String> [4];
```

But when I create it like this:

```
ListNode<String> [] array;
```

I get an error further down when I try to set spots in the array. For example:

```
array[0]=start;
array[1]=start2;
```

Gives me the error "The local variable array may not have been initialized."

How do I fix this? Sorry if this is a basic question! I am in high school.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662394/java-1-6-creating-an-array-of-listt

Comment: When I initialize it the way I did in the first case, it gives me the error "You cannot create a generic array of ListNode<String>."

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize a `ListNode<String>[]` because Java simply doesn't allow generic arrays. In your second snippet, you don't initialize the array, so you can't use it.

To solve this, you'll want to use a list instead of an array:

```
List<ListNode<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
//....
list.add(start);
list.add(start2);
```