# How to create an array of vector in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, vector

So, I want an array of Vector of Integer in Java.

If I put

```
Vector<Integer>[] matrix;
matrix = new Vector<Integer>[100];
```

I get cannot the compilation error

> cannot create a generic array of Vector

Should I use

```
    matrix = new Vector[100];
```

instead? (which gives a warning)

Or should I simply not use an array of vectors and use vector of vector instead?

**Note: I don't want a Vector< Integer >, I want a Vector< Integer >[] to create a matrix of Integers without using Integer[][].**

Comment: am I the only one who struggled to follow this train of thought?

Comment: You should really use [`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead of `Vector`. Is there a particular reason you aren't using an array of arrays, or a v̶e̶c̶t̶o̶r̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶v̶e̶c̶t̶o̶r̶s̶ list of lists?

Comment: List is an interface, you probably mean ArrayList.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Generics Syntax for arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185594/java-generics-syntax-for-arrays)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java simply doesn't have any means to create arrays of a parameterized type without getting or suppressing a warning. So the best you can get is this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Vector<Integer>[] anArray = (Vector<Integer>[]) new Vector<Integer>[100];
```

You can get around this problem if you avoid arrays entirely. I.e.:

```
Vector<Vector<Integer>> list = new Vector<Vector<Integer>>(100);
```

Or with the collection types:

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(100);
```

Comment: Yes, I think suppressing the warning or simply using vector of vector is the only way.

Comment: I know that the answer is 10 years old but the first solution no longer compiles.

Answer (score 3):

```
Vector<Integer> vector = new Vector<Integer>();
```

If you try to do something like this:

```
Vector<Integer> vector = new Vector<Integer>();
Vector<Integer>[] vectors = {vector};
```

You will get a compile error:

> Cannot create a generic array of
>   Vector

However if you don't specify the generic type java will allow it but with a warning:

```
Vector<Integer> vector = new Vector<Integer>();
Vector[] vectors = {vector};
```

Comment: That only creates a single vector, not an array of vectors.

Comment: this seems to be want he wants. I'm still confused as to what he really means by "an array of vector".

Comment: I need an array of vectors, not just a vector. It's similar to Integer[][], but with the inner array being a vector instead of an array, because it needs to increase. I could just use Vector of Vector, but the outer one won't increase so it could just be an array.

Comment: Yes, the last works, but Vector< Vector< Integer > > is better I believe.

Comment: *Generic arrays is not allowed in java* is wrong. Arrays of parameterized types are allowed and essential to the Java language. After all the array based collection classes use them internally (mostly implicit but sometimes explicit).

Answer (score 1):

Vectors are backed by arrays, and will grow or shrink to a size sufficent to hold the element you insert into it.  As such, you can pre-allocate a Vector, but you do not have to actually specify the size at create time.

```
// preallocated vector, which can hold 100 elements
Vector<Integer> integers = new Vector(100);
```

.

```
// default vector, which will probably grow a couple of times when adding 100 element
Vector<Integer> integers = new Vector();
```

A true Java array cannot grow or shrink, and it doesn't support removal of an element from a mid-point.  To allocate an Array, you use

```
// allocate an array
Integer[] integers = new Integer[100];
```

Now if you want to have an "array of vectors" then you would

```
// array of vectors
Vector[] vectors = new Vector[100];
```

Answer (score 0):

To create an array of generic you have to create the non-generic and cast it. You also have to initialise all the elements in the array, otherwise they will be null. :(

```
Vector<Integer>[] anArray = (Vector<Integer>[]) new Vector[100];
for(int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++)
   anArray[i] = new Vector<Integer>();
```

However, since Vector is a legacy class which was replaced by ArrayList in Java 1.2 (1998) I would use List for the interface and ArrayList for the implementation.

```
List<Integer>[] anArray = (List<Integer>[]) new List[100];
for(int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++)
   anArray[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Another option would be to use a collection which held primitive `int` instead of `Integer` Objects. This can enhance performance if you need it.

```
TIntArrayList[] anArray = new TIntArrayList[100];
for(int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++)
   anArray[i] = new TIntArrayList();
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid type casting, consider this implementation:

```
    Vector<Integer>[] intVectorArray;
    Vector[] temp = new Vector[desiredSize];
    intVectorArray = temp;
    for(int i = 0;i<intVectorArray.length;i++){
        hashArray[i] = new Vector<Integer>();
    }
```

The newly created `intVectorArray` will inherit the generic Vector-Array type of `temp` to give you your desired dimensions, and the `for` loop will instantiate your desired datatype.

When you're ready to call `Integer` functions on elements of `intVectorArray`, you will be all set!